# framed environment with fixed image in marginpar

Tags: formatting, environments

I would like to get the exact output below in the `LaTeX`. But unable to fix it and how to set image in the marginpar for each `example` environment.

[image]

[image]

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
\makeatletter
\definecolor{examplecolor}{cmyk}{0.7,0.63,0.07,0}
\definecolor{examplecolortext}{cmyk}{1,0.2,0,0}
\tikzset{
  my example style/.style={font=\bfseries, anchor=west, align=left,     text=examplecolor},
}
\newcounter{example}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\arabic{example}}
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{
  \stepcounter{example}%
  \ifstrempty{#1}%
  {\mdfsetup{%
      frametitle={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node [my example style, text width=.2\linewidth] {\strut     Example~\theexample};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  {\mdfsetup{%
      frametitle={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node (some node) [my example style, text width=.2\linewidth,     inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=-10pt] {\strut Example~\theexample};
          \node [my example style, text=examplecolortext, text     width=.75\linewidth] {\strut\hspace*{-35pt}#1};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \mdfsetup{%
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=examplecolortext,
    linecolor=white,%
    linewidth=0pt,
    frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlerulewidth=2.5pt,
  }\relax
  \begin{mdframed}%
}{%
  \end{mdframed}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{example}[Writing expressions from word descriptions]
Write an expression for each of the following.
\begin{enumerate}
\item 5 more than
\item 3 less than
\item the sum of
\item double the value of
\item the product of
\end{enumerate}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility, using [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) (adjust the settings according to your needs):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{titlecolor}{RGB}{0,135,221}
\definecolor{titleheadcolor}{RGB}{107,88,168}
\definecolor{titlebg}{RGB}{249,252,98}
\definecolor{framebg}{RGB}{252,254,197}

\newtcbtheorem{myexample}{Example}{
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  freelance,
  frame empty,
  interior empty,
  toptitle=5pt,
  bottomtitle=5pt,
  check odd page,
  overlay={
  \ifoddpage
      \node[overlay,anchor=west] 
        at ([xshift=\marginparsep]title.east)
        {\includegraphics[height=22pt]{image-1}};
  \else
      \node[overlay,anchor=east] 
        at ([xshift=-\marginparsep]title.west)
        {\includegraphics[height=22pt]{image-1}};
  \fi
  },
  title code={
    \fill[titlebg] 
      (title.south west) {[rounded corners=10pt] -- 
      (title.north west) --
      (title.north east)} --
      (title.south east) --
      (title.south west);
    \draw[white,line width=3pt]
      (title.south west) -- (title.south east);  
  },
  segmentation code={
    \draw[white,line width=3pt]
      (segmentation.west) -- (segmentation.east);  
  }
  coltitle=titlecolor,
  colback=framebg,
  fonttitle=\sffamily,
  coltitle=titleheadcolor,
  boxrule=0pt,
  description color=titlecolor
}{exa}

\newcommand\SolExp{%
  \par\bigskip\color{titlecolor!90}\textsc{solution}\hfill\textsc{explanation}\hfill\null%
  \tcblower
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myexample}{Writing expressions from world descriptions}{expressions}
\lipsum[4]
\SolExp
\lipsum[4]
\end{myexample}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{myexample}{Writing expressions from world descriptions and a longer title spanning more than one line}{longer}
\lipsum[4]
\SolExp
\lipsum[4]
\end{myexample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's look good and how to align the `title` (please refer updated screenshot) and also `evenpage` image is not placed. How to do..

Comment: @Balaji Please see my updated answer.

Comment: How to add `title` in the `marginpar`?

Comment: @Balaji that is not part of the original question. The original question has been answered in my code. For further, modifications (specially requiring changes not originally stated that might imply large modifications), consider opening follow-up questions.

Comment: If `textheight` is reduced the `example` box is not coming properly. Could you please check and advise?

Comment: @Balaji please provide some minimal, complete code illustrating the problem.

Comment: I have posted this separate questions <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214436/framed-environment-with-fixed-image-in-marginpar-with-title?noredirect=1#comment502939_214436> with MWE.